# Plotting 2 distinct y-axis using rrdtool

Tags: graph, rrdtool, scale, axis

I would like to create a graph with 2 different data sources for y-axis.

For example,

I would like to measure averages of some population on the left Y-axis, and I have another data source which contains how many errors there are in the population.

So lets say I have at a given timeslot A

1,2,3 in my population, with at a error rate of 43%.

I then would like the left axis to plot the average of the measured population, and the right axis would plot the error rate (which is collected outside of the population).

Is this possible in RRDTool today?